# ADF Event trigger based on sharepoint

Tags: azure, sharepoint, azure-data-factory

I have a requirement to trigger ADF pipeline when a file is uploaded into sharepoint. The pipeline copies the file from sharepoint to ADLS. As per my understanding, It is not possible to create storage event trigger based on Sharepoint (as per Microsoft documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-create-event-trigger?tabs=data-factory)

So the alternate approach I am planning is to use a tumbling trigger which will trigger the pipeline every 30 minutes and check if the file is available in the sharepoint location and if it is available it will copy files to ADLS location and another pipeline will be triggered which is event based on ADLS location and does the necessary processing

Can anyone please let me know if this is a good approach or any better approach is recommended. I am pretty new to Azure world.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Best way would be to leverage a logic app/power automate
[image]

which would trigger once the file appears in sharepoint.

Then via logic app, you can trigger the ADF pipeline via its REST API or in built logic app connector

[image]

Comment: Hi Nandan, I know logic app can be used to trigger once file appears in sharepoint. But, I am looking for an approach using azure data factory.  There are some challenges (additional code base,CI/CD process) in bringing a new component (Logic apps) in my current project. So it would be good if you can recommend a better approach using ADF

Comment: Hey @x_coder,
Good day!
Unfortunately ADF doesnt support event based trigger on sharepoint and there is no functionality. So the only way is to check the existence of files on scheduled basis for which you have rightfully thought of the approach